# Glassfish connection pool don't work after restart server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, glassfish, connection-pool

I have a connection pool in Glassfish 3.1 to connect to SqlServer 2008 Express, this pool works fine, but when Glassfish is restarted, the connection pool can't ping and stops working. To work again, I change the url hostname from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" or the contrary...
Apparently this problem just happen when Glassfish is running in Windows Server 2008, when I run Glassfish in a Linux server no problem like this happen...

**EDITED**

```
[#|2012-06-20T14:21:34.992-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ erp_hm_pool ], null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:21:35.006-0300|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RestResponse.getResponse() dá FAILURE. endpoint = 'http://localhost:48/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=erp_hm_pool}'|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.187-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.193-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.194-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.195-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.196-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.197-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:22:42.198-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool erp_hm_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.253-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.255-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.255-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.256-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.257-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.258-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.259-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
[#|2012-06-20T14:23:09.260-0300|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.resizer|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5058: Error while Resizing pool xml_nfe_pool. Exception : null|#]
```

Could someone explain me why is it happening and how can I solve it??